# Adjust floating divs to fill up the container width

Tags: html, css

I have some floating divs in a container:

```
+----------+
| [] [] [] |
| [] [] [] |
| []       |
+----------+
```

These divs have a specific width (300px) and I would like to fit as much in a row as possible.

But the divs should also fill up the remaining space, e.g.: 
container width 1050px = 3 divs fit in, 
divs should resize to fill up the remaining 150px (div width = 350px) till the container width hits 1200px (= 4 divs in a row).

```
+---------+
| [ ] [ ] |
| [ ] [ ] |
| [ ]     |
+---------+
```

So I would like some kind of min-width. Is there any jQuery Plugin to do this or some simple css?

Comment: you could just use percentages for each div, container and divs within the space. I'd use media queries and percentages to adapt to screen sizes.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have no idea how to achive this.. i tried to use min-width 300 on the divs but this just fills the whole width with one div

Comment: Do you have some code or a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S57w3/4/

Answer (score 0):

Actually this can be done easily with `float`

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    border :1px solid red;
    width:105px;
    height:auto;
}
.child{
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9eFm/)

But For good practice you can learn about [Flex Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

Comment: floating is not enought, also the parent must have no fixed with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is closer to what you are looking for:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="innercell">Something</div>
    <div class="innercell">Something</div>
    <div class="innercell">Something</div>
    <div class="innercell">Something</div>
    <div class="innercell">Something</div>
    <div class="innercell">Something</div>
    <div class="innercell">Something</div>
    <div class="innercell">Something</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border :3px solid red;
    width:1000px; /* Change to 100% and drag the frame to see the 'cells' grow */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
}



.innercell {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    border:2px solid green;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pAmfj/3/

**The divs will grow with a larger container div.**

For reference:
http://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/flexbox/flex.html

Comment: hm.. works as i need it, but only in chrome. I need something for ff3.6+ & ie8+ :(

Comment: Yeah, I realised only Chrome (-webkit-) but should give you a clue to locate a version for the other browsers, I think IE is almost the same but with -ie- prefix on the css.